# How to store BOOL in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

view and viewcontroller are separate. I am already tried `NSUserDefaults` it's not working.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:BOOLCondition forKey:@"YES"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

it's say impact conversion of bool to id is disallowed with arc

how to pass that bool value

***** view to viewcontroller not viewcontroller to viewcontroller

Comment: Reading the title, it seems to me you want to pass a value from a view controller to a view. In the question you say “view to viewcontroller”. Which is it?

Comment: Have you tried googling the error before asking a question? Also, you're question/code has nothing to do with view/view controllers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below code to store `BOOL` value in `NSUserDefaults`

`BOOL BOOLCondition = YES;` or `BOOL BOOLCondition = NO;`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:BOOLCondition forKey:@"YES"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: That key name is suspicious.  Looks like the key and value are reversed (i.e. `BOOLCondition` is actually the key)...

Answer (score 4):

I always do this to store a `BOOL` value, because I prefer better to work objects directly:

```
BOOL _myBool = TRUE; // or FALSE...
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@(_myBool) forKey:@"boolValue"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

---

and restoring back the stored value:

```
BOOL _boolValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"boolValue"] boolValue]; // will be FALSE if the value is `nil` for the key
```

Comment: `BOOL` values in Objective-C are `YES` and `NO`, by convention.

Comment: actually I could also use the number `0` for _false_ or number `1` for _true_; it would be the same outcome – as these are the default values for those in Obj-C; nevertheless I could also use any non-zero value for _true_, it'd work as well correctly. :)

Comment: But the convention is to use `YES` and `NO`.

Comment: yes, they would work as well; and I have not denied that convention at all! :) as we both know, in runtime they are pretty much `0` and non-zero (mostly `1`) values which are stored on an `unsigned char` – and the `TRUE` and `FALSE` value are defined as same as the `YES` or `NO`, luckily there won't be any interference exchanging them. ;)

Comment: Is there a difference in the object returned from `@(YES)` and `@(TRUE)`?

Comment: they both look identical to `@(1)`.

Comment: OK, doesn't matter then.